# PIC C - USB_CDC_GETC() and retrieving strings

Tags: c, pic

I'm programming a PIC18F4455 Microcontroller using PIC C.  I'm using the USB_CDC.h header file.  I have a program on the computer sending a string such as "W250025".  However, when I use usb_cdc_getc() to get the first char, it freezes.  Sometimes the program sends only 'T', so I really want to just get the first character.

Why does my code never execute past received=usb_cdc_getc(); when I send "W250025"?

```
if (usb_cdc_kbhit())
      {
         //printf(lcd_putc, "Check 3"); delay_ms(3000); printf(lcd_putc, "\f");
         received = usb_cdc_getc();
         printf(lcd_putc, "Received "); lcd_putc(received); delay_ms(3000); printf(lcd_putc, "\f");
         if (received == 'W'){   //waveform
            disable_interrupts(INT_TIMER1);
            set_adc_channel(0);
            load_and_print_array(read_into_int(), read_into_int());}
         else if (received == 'T'){ //temperature
            set_adc_channel(1);
            enable_interrupts(INT_TIMER1);}
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics of the PIC microcontroller, but, assuming that `usb_cdc_getc` behaves like the normal `getc`, the most likely cause is that your characters aren't reaching the function, which normally blocks. Are you sending a newline? It could also be a hardware problem where the characters aren't reaching your uC in the first place.

If it is the former, and not the desired behavior there likely is a nonblocking `getch` equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

> `usb_cdc_getc()` - Gets a character from the receive buffer.  If
>   there is no data in the receive buffer it will wait until
>   there is data in the receive buffer.  If you do not want 
>   to wait in an infinit loop, use `usb_cdc_kbhit()` first to
>   check if there is data before calling `usb_cdc_getc()`."

from https://github.com/tkrworks/PICnome-Firmware/blob/master/usb_cdc.h